# How i get from a file a pair of tuples in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Hi I try to get training set from  a file and return a list of a pair of tuples like here 
[('yes', 40, 'good'),('more'), ...]

I tried to do it in this way

[('yes', 40, 'good'),('more',), ...] with the comma in the second tuple

what  i really want is to remove the comma at the second tuple

Code

```
def gettrain():
# >>>>> YOUR CODE HERE
with open('health-train.txt','r') as health_test:


    d = list()
    lable = list()
    Data = (line.strip().split(',') for line in health_test)
    #Data = [(smoke, int(age), diet, lable) for smoke, age, diet, lable in Data]
    for smoke, age, diet, lable in Data:
        d.extend([(smoke, int(age), diet), (lable,)])


return d
# <<<<< END YOUR CODE
```

Output:

```
[('yes', 54, 'good'),
('less',),
('no', 55, 'good'),
('less',),
('no', 26, 'good'),
('less',),
('yes', 40, 'good'),
('more',),
('yes', 25, 'poor'),
('less',),
('no', 13, 'poor'),
('more',),
('no', 15, 'good'),
('less',),
('no', 50, 'poor'),
('more',),
('yes', 33, 'good'),
('more',),
('no', 35, 'good'),
('less',),
('no', 41, 'good'),
('less',),
('yes', 30, 'poor'),
('more',),
('no', 39, 'poor'),
('more',),
('no', 20, 'good'),
('less',),
('yes', 18, 'poor'),
('less',),
('yes', 55, 'good'),
('more',)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve.
The comma after the string just indicates that it is a one element tuple/
If you want a structure like `[((str, int, str), str), ...]` then you need to remove extra brackets:

```
def gettrain():
# >>>>> YOUR CODE HERE
    with open('health-train.txt','r') as health_test:
        d = list()
        Data = (line.strip().split(',') for line in health_test)
        for smoke, age, diet, lable in Data:
            d.extend([((smoke, int(age), diet), lable)])

    return d
# <<<<< END YOUR CODE
```

Comment: I want it to be look like this
('yes', 54, 'good'),('less') list of tow pair of tuples but without the comma after the element in the second tuple like i did here
('yes', 54, 'good'),('less',)

Comment: This comma is a part of __repr__ method for tuple. It will always be present when printing single element tuple eg. `print(("foo",))` [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710455/why-single-element-tuple-is-interpreted-as-that-element-in-python].

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer